# why can't you consistently deploy an EJB

Tags: ejb

I need to know what factors contribute to not being able to deploy an EJB. I have an error like this:

```
An error has occurred
Deploying application in domain failed;
Error loading deployment descriptors for module [blach]
Referencing error: This bundle has no bean of name [blah]
Error loading deployment descriptors for module [blah]
Referencing error: This bundle has no bean of name [blah]
```

Answer (score 0):

"Error loading deployment descriptors" sounds like the deployment descriptor is broken. I'd try validating it against the DTD, and perhaps crank up the log level of the app server to try and get more detailed error messages.